# Multiple option arguments using getopts in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopts

I am trying to process command line arguments using `getopts` in bash. One of the requirements is for the processing of an arbitrary number of option arguments (without the use of quotes).

1st example (only grabs the 1st argument)

```
madcap:~/projects$ ./getoptz.sh -s a b c
-s was triggered
Argument: a
```

2nd example (I want it to behave like this but without needing to quote the argument"

```
madcap:~/projects$ ./getoptz.sh -s "a b c"
-s was triggered
Argument: a b c
```

Is there a way to do this?

Here's the code I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":s:" opt; do
    case $opt in
    s) echo "-s was triggered" >&2
       args="$OPTARG"
       echo "Argument: $args"
       ;;
       \?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
       ;;
    :) echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
    esac
done
```

Note that I want to support multiple flags this way, e.g.

```
madcap:~/projects$ ./getoptz.sh -s a b c -u 1 2 3 4
-s was triggered
Argument: a b c
-u was triggered
Argument: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's this used for?  It's unusual for options to work this way.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the best way to go is using -s for each argument, i.e. `-s foo -s bar -s baz`, **but** if you still want to support several arguments for a single option, I suggest you to **not** use `getopts`.

Please take a look at the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a sargs=()

read_s_args()
{
    while (($#)) && [[ $1 != -* ]]; do sargs+=("$1"); shift; done
}

while (($#)); do
    case "$1" in
        -s) read_s_args "${@:2}"
    esac
    shift
done

printf '<%s>' "${sargs[@]}"
```

When `-s` is being detected, `read_s_args` is invoked with the remaining options and arguments on the command line. `read_s_args` reads its arguments until it reaches the next option. Valid arguments to -s are being stored in the `sargs` array.

Here is a **sample output**:

```
[rany$] ./script -s foo bar baz -u a b c -s foo1 -j e f g
<foo> <bar> <baz> <foo1>
[rany$]
```

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the downvote on this answer, it appears to work fine and be fairly sustainable. If you are considering downvoting, please at least state why so that the answer can be improved.

Comment: @ChrisDown Is this comment directed to a specific user?

Comment: Yes, this answer was downvoted, but I can't see why.